# What is the probability that $Ax = y$ for a random matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, modular-arithmetic, random-matrices

Let $m, q,$ and $n$ be integers and $m$ be much greater than $n$. Let $q$ also be a prime number.

Consider an $m \times n$ matrix $A$. Each entry of $A$ is chosen uniformly at random from $\mathbb{Z}_q$.

For two particular vectors $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{q}^{n \times 1}$  and $y \in \mathbb{Z}_{q}^{m \times 1},$ I am trying to compute

$$\underset{A}{\text{Pr}}~[Ax = y]. $$

All the operations (addition and multiplication) are modulo $q$.

---

Here's my qualitative intuition.

Since $A$ should be full rank with high probability, I believe that the image of $A$ should be uniformly distributed and that the probability in question should be $\frac{1}{q^{m}}$.

Comment: I think you have to add additional information on the vectors $x,y$. Consider for example the vector $x = (z,z,z,z,...)$ and $y= (z+1,z+1,...)$ where $z$ divides $q$ and is not equal to $1$. Then you cannot reach this with any $A$.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that everything was integer valued!

Comment: @a_student Why can I not reach it for any $A$?

Comment: Additionally, what if $q$ is a prime number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is the zero vector then of course the probability will be either $0$ or $1$ (depending on $y$), because $Ax$ will always be $0$ as well. Otherwise, suppose without loss of generality that $x_n \ne 0$.

We can write $Ax$ as $A_1 x_1 + A_2 x_2 + \dots + A_n x_n$, where $A_i \in \mathbb Z_q^m$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of $A$. Let's pick $A$ randomly in two stages: first pick $A_1$ through $A_{n-1}$, and second pick $A_n$.

Regardless of what happens in the first stage, we will have $A x = y$ if and only if
$$
    A_n = \frac1{x_n}\left(y - A_1 x_1 - A_2 x_2 - \dots - A_{n-1} x_{n-1}\right).
$$
(Here, $\frac1{x_n}$ is the inverse of $x_n$ modulo $q$.)

This happens with probability $\frac1{q^m}$, because there is only one possible value in $\mathbb Z_q^m$ that $A_n$ can have.

Note that it is not necessary to assume anything about the relative sizes of $m$ and $n$. No matter what they are, if $A$ is chosen uniformly at random and $x$ is not the zero vector, then $Ax$ is uniformly distributed.

Comment: A sanity check: does your proof technique mean that no matter what the distributions of $A_1, \ldots, A_{n-1}$ are, as we pick the entries of $A_{n}$ uniformly at random, the required probability is $\frac{1}{q^{m}}$?

Comment: No, since if the distributions of $A_1, \dots, A_{n-1}$ are different from the distribution of $A_n$, then we can no longer go from "$x \ne 0$" to "without loss of generality, $x_n \ne 0$". But if we are given that $x_n \ne 0$ ahead of time then yes, the distributions of $A_1, \dots, A_{n-1}$ no longer matter.

Comment: Do you have any intuition for what happens when we slightly extend the question and ask for the probability $\text{Pr}[Ax_1 = y_1 ~\text{and}~   Ax_2 = y_2]$ for four fixed vectors $x_1, y_1, x_2$ and $y_2$ and a random choice of $A$? I was wondering whether the probability is $\frac{1}{q^{2m}}$ or something close to that --- but a simple argument of the form above does not seem to work.

Comment: For this problem, the nondegeneracy condition (similar to "$x$ is not the zero vector" above) is that there are positions $i,j$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}x_{1i} & x_{1j} \\ x_{2i} & x_{2j}\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible. If so, then we can argue that after picking all columns of $A$ except for $A_i$ and $A_j$, there is a unique way to pick those two columns, giving us a probability of $\frac1{q^{2m}}$. But if there are no two positions $i,j$ like that, then one of $x_1, x_2$ is a multiple of the other, and one equation $Ax_i = y_i$ either implies the other or rules it out.

Comment: Thanks! One last question: developing your technique further, what happens when we want to see whether $\text{Pr}[Ax_1 = y_1~\text{and}~Ax_2 = y_2~\cdots~\text{and}~Ax_k = y_k] = \frac{1}{q^{km}}$ for some $k > n$? The non-degeneracy condition for which the equality would hold is when no $x_i$ is a multiple of any linear combination of the other $x_i$s. But, now $k$ is more than the number of columns $A$ has, so the column-picking trick would not hold. I guess we argue something about the linear independence of the images?

Comment: Yes. There will be some $j \le n$ equations that are linearly independent, and then from those we can either deduce all the other equations (in which case we can drop those equations from the probability) or deduce a contradiction to those other equations (in which case the probability will be $0$.)

Comment: That makes me a bit confused. When $k > n$, what is the probability $\text{Pr}[Ax_1 = y_1~\text{and}~\cdots~Ax_k=y_k]$? Is it always $\frac{1}{q^{jm}}$ for some $j \leq n$? Or can it be $\frac{1}{q^{km}}$ for some choices of $x_i$s? I had thought the latter, but your argument seems to suggest the former.

Comment: Never mind. I think I understand. There can be at most only $n$ linearly independent $x_i$s and hence the probability will always be $\frac{1}{q^{jm}}$ for some $j$ less than $n$.